# Chrome with Let's Encrypt (Plesk): Old Cyphersuite

Tags: google-chrome, plesk, lets-encrypt

I used the Plesk extension for Let's Encrypt (https://github.com/plesk/letsencrypt-plesk), but chrome shows that an old cypher suite is used. The certificate uses:

- TLS 1.2
- AES_256_CBC
- HMAC-SHA1
- ECDHE_RSA

I found out that AES_256_CBC seems to be the problem, but the UI does not allow for any configuration of these parameters.
Is there a configuration file that allows this?
I only found http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#configuration-file which does not seem to support these options

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For server-wide you can change:

- for nginx, `ssl_ciphers` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf` to:

`ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM+AES128:EECDH+AESGCM+AES256:EDH+AESGCM+AES128:EDH+AESGCM+AES256;`

- for apache, `SSLCipherSuite` in file like `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf`:

`SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM+AES128:EECDH+AESGCM+AES256:EDH+AESGCM+AES128:EDH+AESGCM+AES256`

Per individual site you can use same strings in additional web server directives for Apache/Nginx:
[image: plesk apache/nginx per-site options]

Additionally Plesk has all-in-one tool for hardening security options in all supported services:

`plesk sbin pci_compliance_resolver --enable`